# PHP PDO bindValue does not update the DB

Tags: php, pdo

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

If I use the code below, I am able to update the DB.

```
            $sUpdateSql = "UPDATE googleAnalytics SET $period = '$value' WHERE statisticName = '$item' ";
            $preparedStatement = $db->query($sUpdateSql);
```

However, with the statement below the DB does not update.

```
            $sUpdateSql = "UPDATE googleAnalytics SET $period = '?' WHERE statisticName = '?' ";
            $preparedStatement = $db->prepare($sUpdateSql);
            /* bind parameters for markers */
            $preparedStatement->bindValue(1, $value);
            $preparedStatement->bindValue(2, $item);
            $preparedStatement->execute();
```

Comment: Plus no need of `quotes` while making placeholder

Comment: The OP isn't replacing column names @Saty.

Comment: Aren't both statements PDO? Only one binds the parameters and the other doesn't.

Comment: @JayBlanchard !! Thanks for correcting me!!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php would have helped you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around the question marks.

`bindValue` handles escaping the strings.

Just an FYI, you can also name your params.

```
"SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = :id"

bindValue('id', $id);
```